# Java Stream<String> stream display only first 10 lines from txt file

Tags: java

This code reads the contents of my txt file. I would like my code to read only the first 10 lines.

```
public void loadDataFromTxt() {
    String fileName = "/Users/pietrzakadrian/Desktop/file.txt";

    try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName))) {

        stream.forEach(System.out::println);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: `stream.limit(10).forEach(System.out::println);`

Answer (score 8):

You can use the [`Stream#limit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#limit-long-) method:

```
String fileName = "/Users/pietrzakadrian/Desktop/file.txt";
try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName))) {
    stream.limit(10).forEach(System.out::println);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Example Stream:

```
Stream.of(5,4,3,1)
    .limit(2)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output:

> 5
>
> 4